# Forge Design Automation Example Not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I'm new to Forge Design Automation and am trying to start from one of the example projects provided by Autodesk(https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit). I think all the settings are in the right place, Revit version is matching, but for some reasons it keeps giving me this error for the workitems.

The full error report is as below. I found a similar question already posted on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find a right answer from the thread. Thank you in advance!

```
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[inputFile].path) /al $(appbundles[CountItAppBundle].path)"
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "dasreportfailedlimits": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532"
"ActivityId":"oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ.CountItActivity+dev"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit!34"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ.CountItAppBundle!4"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "inputFile": {
    "localName": "$(inputFile)",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:SyWMnjIfMaFwA984Pg67EqBHlmI=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:QTWKPH0paYCgDR3dyHyhSzCeTb8="
    }
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "data:application/json, {'walls':true,'floors':true,'doors':true,'windows':true}"
  },
  "outputTxt": {
    "localName": "result.txt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:WXUaP1osRq8ajEaxt+zKp+tk5lY=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:QTWKPH0paYCgDR3dyHyhSzCeTb8="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onComplete": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "optional": true,
    "url": "http://5810d13a.ngrok.io/Masked:utboh2Koq1ixxbiKAgZbqRy/IY4=",
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3512,\"client_id\":\"oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitDownloads": 200,
  "limitUploads": 200,
  "limitDownloadSizeMB": 2000,
  "limitUploadSizeMB": 2000,
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Starting work item 8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Start preparing AppPackage CountItAppBundle.
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Start download phase.
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Download bits and install app to local cache.
[05/21/2020 22:22:37] Start downloading file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/testqto/objects/DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Embedded resource [ {'walls':true,'floors':true,'doors':true,'windows':true}] is saved as file: T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\params.json.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] '6217728' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] End downloading file https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/testqto/objects/DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] End download phase.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Command line: [ /i T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt /al T:\Aces\Applications\9ec5d863afc8cb26f3b1bb44b33ec0af.oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ.CountItAppBundle[4].package]
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Start script phase.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532 "T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\userdata" /exe "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\19.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe"  /i T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt /al T:\Aces\Applications\9ec5d863afc8cb26f3b1bb44b33ec0af.oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ.CountItAppBundle[4].package.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Running in unattended mode.
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\19.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Echoing command line args:
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   0:/i
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\DAL_1920
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   2:McKinney_EC_2019.rvt
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   3:/al
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   4:T:\Aces\Applications\9ec5d863afc8cb26f3b1bb44b33ec0af.oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ.CountItAppBundle[4].package
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   5:/isolate
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   6:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532
[05/21/2020 22:22:38]   7:T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\userdata
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Running RevitAssemblyResolver....
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Initializing RevitCoreEngine...
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\Revit2019
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[05/21/2020 22:22:38] Running user application....
[05/21/2020 22:22:42] Exception: Revit input file not found: T:\Aces\Jobs\8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532\DAL_1920
[05/21/2020 22:22:42] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[05/21/2020 22:22:42] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] End script phase.
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[05/21/2020 22:22:43] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/oIOFqYHZbnyfZeUY43azItH5mytP93AJ/8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3CJRD6G6D&Expires=1590114158&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEN3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIGucnbT6c0SkIKRtstBvwrZlL5I1Gmrl%2FLETCtuKg7b2AiEAjycnNMp4lTNPCDeHAQH5G2ZW%2Fiub0PqiezJY0iDC5W8q1QEINhABGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDMfJazlOw4VV%2F5Mn7iqyARXbPohi7phLE%2B4k7bkTiRPZVCgTVcwB4mcjNWivj7R9xjxoK%2BR4IftWwziWKRXzYigTBMI1PxV2BDq4DL6CyuiBuejKMw7JipaP2c3Nx%2FOgD5cYIxVBAyRu3I8j5ZiWdOJOOAKLzyNTjfDwEMz1A31q3791QizfxLN8i3VOwNTGbSFYVr%2FGXe4THlhoplwpcK3fWp8eHnWfxGu3sdMD623YyamnnwpEzh7jhO1Q4rBoDA0wtNWb9gU64AGtaXWJUp85C45WZUGWV%2FBILXnCTKjAspKObgA3dprrUX9YjZD4W%2FCl2Q60nty1YMP88pdRyFbmsUOZwjoL9zvInaFg8xdpi5xTYml7PxGLQ7Pg2Z2YT%2BRyr73cDgL%2Fge7B6zCFTTOg8FkK4CaQ%2BNelp%2BLq3s3JdI2bgdhu%2FosKLtXLusTt64DgFJ0Qi0ZGWGR%2B79aCjjoyKnuh1VNM8iPfr2bsllbtYPybOvQE6b0ANHfMerZ0zum4l8UGXlt2xYd1iOdBX9SSJstv8u0FOlu9%2BDJbnamffWq4PDZwpu1o0w%3D%3D&Signature=DJG66Q0tALB2im6gfkhCqqac%2BWs%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-05-21T22:22:37.7292586Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-05-21T22:22:37.9978819Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2020-05-21T22:22:38.4249503Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2020-05-21T22:22:43.6485467Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 6217785
  },
  "id": "8ec3d7cabe574f47a8cc1c8b4ce2e532"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file has a space in it `DAL_1920 McKinney_EC_2019.rvt`.

You could either provide an input file without a spaces or escape the path in the command line like so:

```
"$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al $(appbundles[CountItAppBundle].path)"
```

See the blog for more details:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-command-line

Comment: Oh sweet! I got rid of the space in the file name and it worked! Thanks so much for shedding some lights. I'm trying to incorporate my BIM 360 hub to source the models. In that case, how would the spaces in the file name on BIM 360 affect this workflow?

Comment: See PR:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit/pull/5
(This shall let you use spaces in file names)

Comment: Ah awesome! So I can just simply update the source code of the WebApp per your suggestion. Thank you so much! Learned another thing today.